# NestedScrollView not work with FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Can anyone help me with NestedScrollView, I'm using this component it is hiding my ActionBar as it should, however I have a GridView with a gallery of images and when I scroll to see more images it does not let us use Scroll.

I've done everything I can imagine, I've looked everywhere, I've been trying to convert it for almost 2 days: '(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_main">
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

GridFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmento_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLoader"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
        android:background="@color/grid_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Mako on 1/13/2017.
 */
public class dataFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private class sliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



        final  String tabs[]={"tab1", "tab2"};
        public sliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = GridFragment.newInstance("6360392529587060753");


            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }
    }



}
```

Video demonstrating problem:
[Example](https://a.uguu.se/EAJoMYI1l08h_Buongiorno%2CPomeriggio%2CSera%2CNotte.mp4)